# Need to update existing schema for all documents

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, mongoose

I am updating a schema for a database that already holds records. How do I add an additional field - "deviceAccess", default to "false"

Existing schema:

```
deviceId: "03",
    switches:[
        {
            _id: '03',
            switchesID:'03',
            switchName:'Laptop'
        }
    ]
```

Schema I want:

```
deviceId: "03",
    switches:[
        {
            _id: '03',
            switchesID:'03',
            switchName:'Laptop',
            deviceAccess: 'False'
        }
    ]
```

I want so for all the devices existing! Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write a **migration script** to update all of your docs in a collection:

use npm package [**mongodb-migrate**](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongodb-migrate) to do this:

**install it:**

```
npm install mongodb-migrate
```

**script:**

```
var mongodb = require('mongodb');

exports.up = function(db, next){
    const your_collection = db.collection("your_collection_name");

    yout_collection.update({},
           {$set:{"switches.deviceAccess": false}},
           {multi: true},
           (err, data)=>{
                 //todo
                 next();
           })

};

exports.down = function(db, next){
    next();
};
```

**run:**

```
node ./node_modules/mongodb-migrate -runmm -dbc '{ "host":"<db_hostIp_address>","db":"<db_name>","port":<db_port>}' up
```

> **Note:**
>
> Don't forget to update your schema with
>
> `deviceAccess: {type: Boolean, default: false}`

Answer (score 0):

Three things are in my mind. I would recommend the first one.

- You don't need to add it at all. If the key `deviceAccess` doesn't exists then consider it `false`. You can take advantage of schema less behavior of noSQL.
- Run an update command to add the new key. You should do it only if the collection is small.
- Perform the second option but partially. Like, update first 100 then wait like 4-10 seconds then update next 100 (101-200).

Hope it helps.

Comment: Was unable to write the update code, could you help me with that? In javascript, (nodejs)

Comment: Example: `MyModel.updateMany({}, { $set: { "switches.deviceAccess": 'foo' } });`. If it doesn't find `deviceAccess` property then it will add it. Make sure to update your Mongoose schema accordingly. Documentation here: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/documents.html#updating